# Style changes to Text while I want to be Input

Tags: input, text-formatting

I do know what happened to my Mathematica. I frequently have to change the style from Text to Input to write codes. How I can re-change this unwanted issue?

Comment: May be you hit Alt-7 by mistake while typing?

Comment: Hi Nasser, I do not know ,but I have to change it for every trying to enter codes. From text to input.

Answer (score 3):

Select the menu item `Format > Options Inspector...`. Then, from the Scope dropdown menu, select the appropriate scope you wish to apply this to, which presumably is `Global Preferences`. Then type "cellstyle" in the Search box. Among the items selected/displayed will be `DefaultNewCellStyle`.

Since your question implies this happens all the time, the value for `DefaultNewCellStyle` is probably "Text". If so, there will be a small 'x' in a circle to the left of the option name. Clicking the circled 'x' will revert the value to the system default of "Input". You could also change the value directly by typing "Input" (including the quotes) in the Value column.